# loading a borderless window from a xib with view

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I am trying to load a borderless window from a .xib in my program. I can load a borderless window with by overriding `[[[NSWindow]] initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:]` as follows:

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag {

    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:bufferingType defer:flag];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self setOpaque:NO];
    [self setHasShadow:YES];
    [self setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [self setAlphaValue:1.0];

    // Ignore events
    [self setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES];

    return self;    
}
```

When another method which contains `[self orderFront:self];` is called, a window shows. However, I have a separate .xib file with a window created that I want to show when this method is called. I have the file's owner set as NSApplication and the window itself is of the class that contains the aforementioned code. How do I, when I call the method with  `[self orderFront:self];`, load the window in the xib and show it instead of this class creating a window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can use `NSWindowController` to load an `NSWindow` from a separate nib (or xib) file.  Sub-class NSWindowController, and put your controller code in there. Create that object in the xib file and set that to be the file's owner. Link the NSWindow to the NSWindowController's delegate outlet.

Then it's as easy as:

```
NSWindowController * windowController = [[[YourWindowClass alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"YourWindowClass"] autorelease];
NSWindow * sheet = [windowController window];
```

Comment: thanks for your help - while this wasn't exactly what i wanted to do, an example project with this code helped!